Node - File Upload works with http but not with https
If I use const http = require('http'); then the upload works correctly, the files are transferred, but if I change it to const https = require('https') then it no longer works and throws code 500.
I use the multer library. The uploads directory is where the app.js server file is, and permissions are 755. Keys pem are added. sd
My HTTPS Code:
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');  // Zmiana na 'https'
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './cert/key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './cert/cert.pem'))
}

const app = express();
const server = https.createServer(options, app);  // Zmiana na HTTPS server

const port = 24006;

// Konfiguracja miejsca zapisu plików
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');  // Upewnij się, że katalog 'uploads' istnieje
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

// Inicjalizacja multer z konfiguracją zapisu
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Endpoint POST do przesyłania plików
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
    }
    res.send(`File uploaded successfully: ${req.file.filename}`);
});

// Start serwera
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on https://localhost:${port}`);  // Zmiana na HTTPS URL
});


Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Machine Status</title>
   
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   

    <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="*/*">
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
    
    
    
    <script>
    document.getElementById('uploadForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Zapobieganie domyślnej akcji formularza

    const formData = new FormData(this);

    fetch('/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Have you verified that your pem files are valid and accessible? Does a simple get request over https work for instance?

this is how pem files work

Now I figured out that the situation looks like this:
I have the application running on port 24006, now that I have entered the address with the port: https://www.adress.net:24006/
and in the fetch of the index.html file I have also set it with the port:
fetch('https://www.adress.net:24006/upload', {
method: 'POST',
body: formData
})
The file upload works.
And now I don't understand... after all, users use the www address without ports: https://www.adress.net/
I tried to set the app.js application to the standard port 443, but it throws access denied.
So how do I set everything to work on port 24006 without having to add this port to the website address every time?
